# Rails disable SQL generated aliases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

How do **Rails generate aliases in SQL** works? And how can I disable it in the development log?

**Example** of generating aliases:

```
SELECT DISTINCT "cards"."id" AS t0_r0, "cards"."user_id" AS t0_r1, "cards"."area_id" AS 
t0_r2, "cards"."group_id" AS t0_r3, "cards"."type" AS t0_r4, "cards"."kind" AS t0_r5, 
"cards"."color" AS t0_r6, "cards"."title" AS t0_r7, "cards"."description" AS t0_r8,.....
```

This kind of aliases doesn't bother my logic but **it complicates my debugging**. Sometimes generated SQL is more than a thousand words.

Edit:

> When there are no includes specified—so there is only one table
>   involved in the query— the SELECT clause is an asterisk (*) for
>   simplicity. However, once you include other models into your find
>   call, the columns become specified and are aliased so Active Record
>   can tell them apart.

Comment: These aliases are how rails actually maps the result rows to the model instances. Look at a query with eager loads if you want an example. If you "turn them off" you're going to break AR completely.

Comment: But can I set aliases "invisible" in a logger or something like that? Can you provide some links so I can read more?

Comment: I don't really have a single source - you would have to dig through the source of ActiveRecord if you want to know how it works internally. I don't think there is a provision to filter this out.

Comment: OK, I will take a look. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if your query is that long the issue is often that you're passing an array somewhere and have a monster `WHERE id IN (............)` instead of a subquery.